# Simple yet somehow hard Statistical Hypothesis Testing

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to understand Statistical Hypothesis Tests.

---

I have a dice that gives a six with probability 1/6 and I want to see if it really is the case.

$$H_0: \ p=\frac{1}{6} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ H_1: \ p \neq \frac{1}{6}$$
With $\alpha = 5\%$

The dice is thrown 18 times and we get 6 sixes. Can we reject $H_0$?

---

First of all, I see that its a two sided interval but I can't use Normal distribution since n<30 so I need to use $t_a(n-1)$ with n=18 and $a/2=0.025$ gives $t_{0.025}(17)=2.11$. I know that the p-value should somehow be 0.1028 with the answer "No we cant reject $H_0$" but I am at a loss of how to get there. How do I solve this?

[Source of the problem (in Swedish).](https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/sf1901/S/2016/Material/L13.pdf)

Comment: You can't use $t$ either.  Just use the Binomial Distribution as is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test

Comment: Working from the given answer, $0.1028$ is the probability of seeing $6$ or more sixes or of seeing $0$ or fewer sixes using the binomial distribution.

Comment: Just use a binomial distribution to find the probability that an event with a probability of $1/6$ will occur 6 or more times out of a sample of 18. That probability will be greater than 0.05, so no you cannot draw a conclusion.

Comment: When n is moderately large up to a 100 or maybe 200, current computer powers is preferred over normal approximation. And advantage is that you get exact tests as opposed to approximate (with unknown degree of approximation).

Comment: With observed $x=6$ sixes in $n=18$ rolls, you could use an exact binomial test in R: code `binom.test(6, 18, p=1/6)` to get P-value $0.1028,$ not rejecting at 5% level and also 95% CI $( 0.1334274, 0.5900748
)$ for $p,$ which contains $1/6.$  With such a small $n$ you can't get reliable results using normal approximations.

Comment: As @Henry says: under $H_0,$ you have $X\sim\mathsf{Binom}(n=18, p = 1/6),$ so that $1-P(1\le X\le 5) \approx 0.1026.$ In R: code `1-sum(dbinom(1:5, 18, 1/6))` returns
$0.1028261.$

Answer (score 2):

As you say, you can't use a normal approximation. In R the procedure `binom.test` does an exact binomial test of $H_0: p = 1/6$ against $H_a: p\ne 1/6$, as shown below. With $X = 6$ successes in $n=18$ trials, $H_0$ is not rejected at the 5% level of significance.

```
binom.test(6, 18, p=1/6)

        Exact binomial test

data:  6 and 18
number of successes = 6, number of trials = 18, 
 p-value = 0.1028
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.1666667
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1334274 0.5900748
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.3333333
```

As @Henry has commented, the P-value is computed
under the null distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n=18,\, p=1/6),$
which has $1 - P(1 \le X \le 5) = 0.1028,$ to four places. (See slide 12 in your link for the method.)

```
1-sum(dbinom(1:5, 18, 1/6))
[1] 0.1028261
```

The figure below shows the null distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n=18,\, p = 1/6);$ the P-value is the total height of the
heavy blue bars.

[image]

Comment: Why are you excluding zero (in the calculation of the $p$-value)?

Comment: Both on the graph (blue bar at 0) and in the R code I am including probability for 0. I am _excluding_ probabilities for 1 through 5. As in the R code  `1-sum(dbinom(1:5, 18, 1/6))`.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X \sim \mathsf{Bin}(18, 1/6).$ Then $\mathbf{P}(X \geq 6) = 0.06526505$ (using $\mathtt{R}$). Under your "null hypothesis", your dice has the same distribution as $X$ and the probability of seeing $6$ or more sixes, is about $6.5\%$, which would not be inconsistent with the "null hypothesis" if you want to set the cut-off at $5\%$. Please note that it is not very sensical to exclude zero (I don't know who suggested you to do such thing). In fact, $\mathbf{P}(X = 0) = (\dfrac{5}{6})^{18} = 0.03756104$ which is pretty large.